# When data is selected, details in view are shattered. using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, materialize

I have a problem in my code, when I select a data I want to show other details in view.

In first select, show correct detail.
In second select, show first and second data and in view are shattered.

For example, I have some client:

```
1. Client Name: Name 1. Telephone: 1234656. Adress: St. G.W.Bush, London
2. Client Name: Name 2. Telephone: 2222222. Adress: St. G.W, NY
3. Client Name: Name 3. Telephone: 3333333. Adress: St. A.B, Cuba
4. Client Name: Name 4. Telephone: 4444444. Adress: St. G.P.L, Germany
```

1. When Select Name 1, in detals show Telephone: 1234656. Adress: St. G.W.Bush, London
2. When Select Name 2, in details show Telephone: 2222222. Adress: St. G.W, NY
3. When Select Name 3, in details show Telephone: 1234656. Adress: St. G.W.Bush, London

My html code:

```
 <div class="input-field col s4">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Data:</legend>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="selectedClient.client_id" formControlName="client_id" id="client_id"
          materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="client">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Name :</option>
          <option *ngFor="let item of client" [value]="item.client_id">{{item.clientName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        Telephone:
        <p>{{selectedClient.contactNo}}</p>
        <br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-field col s12" >
        Adress:
        <p>{{selectedClient.address}}</p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
```

TS Component:

```
 onSelect(clientid) {
  let selectedClient = new Client('')
   this.selectedClient = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.client.length; i++) {
      if (this.client[i].client_id === clientid) {
        this.selectedClient = this.client[i];
       }
    }
  }
```

I create this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqmugb-vjlydd?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.html) example

Any idea please?

Comment: The example is different from your Question, please fix everything and tell exactly whats your problem right now, and If you are still playing with the example, just fork it and change the fork because we can't track your live changes to a specific problem when the errors changes by you.

Comment: Yes, I create a demo only for reference. In post, is code. And problem is, When I select client 1, Telephone and adress show correct, but when I select other client, in details show other details with first client, when I change it agin, client name change but details no. Works not good. This maybe, because this `onSelect(clientid) {}` show: first select, show only 1 client, in secont select show 2 client, that in it are change value

Comment: @dAxx_  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqmugb-y83cr4?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove from:

```
<select (change)="onSelectt($event.target.value)" 
 [(ngModel)]="selecteditem.id_item" formControlName="id_item" 
 id="id_item" materialize="material_select" 
>
```

the part of : `[(ngModel)]` it is messing your data and you dont need two way binding since you are only display the data selected value. I've tested it in your example and it is working.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are making it more complex then it needs to be.

- Use the object in the `*ngFor` directly and bind it to `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]` which supports binding to an object as `[value]` binding is limited to primitive types only (like strings and numbers).
- Get rid of the `change` event binding as well as the method it is bound to.
- Use [safe navigation operator ( ?. ) and null property paths](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-operators) in your template when referencing the selected object. You could also enclose the whole block in an `<div *ngIf="selecteditem">` where the inner html does something with the selection. Here is the relevant and changed template code:

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqmugb-nlk314)

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Data:</legend>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select [(ngModel)]="selecteditem" name="id_item" formControlName="id_item" id="id_item" materialize="material_select">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Name :</option>
      <option *ngFor="let item of options" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
     id:<p>{{selecteditem?.id_item}}</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="input-field col s12" >
    Adress:<p>{{selecteditem?.adress}}</p>
    <br>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```